# Create a nested list from a object

Tags: javascript

I have the following object

```
var json = {
    items:[
        {id:45 , lable:"Test 1.2.1", parent_id: 2},
        {id:12, lable:"Test 1.0", parent_id: 0},
        {id:32, lable:"Test 1.1", parent_id: 12},
        {id:2, lable:"Test 1.2", parent_id: 12}
    ]
}
```

Using this object i needed to create a nested list, which will look like the following in the browser

- Test 1.0

  - Test 1.1
  - Test 1.2

    - Test 1.2.1

My approach was to write a function that would go through the object and store the values in the array of list of elements

```
function appendItems(json){
    var list = json.items;
    var listelem = [];

    list.forEach(function(i){
        var listelements = document.createElement('li');
        listelements.setAttribute("id",i.id);
        listelements.setAttribute("data-parent-id", i.parent_id);
        listelements.innerText = i.lable;
        listelem.push(listelements);

    })

    console.log(listelem);    
}
```

But i am unsure of how to get that nested structure from this point

Comment: Are you open to look at plugins like [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/)? If not it will need recursion.

Comment: no plugins trying to achieve this via pure js

Comment: So no to jquery too, right?

Comment: @ndd right no jquery

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would start by transforming you array into an actual tree. You could do it like this:

```js
var obj = {
    items:[
        {id:45 , lable:"Test 1.2.1", parent_id: 2},
        {id:12, lable:"Test 1.0", parent_id: 0},
        {id:32, lable:"Test 1.1", parent_id: 12},
        {id:2, lable:"Test 1.2", parent_id: 12}
    ]
}

// first we create a dictionary so we can find elements by id easily
var objDict = obj.items.reduce(function(p,c) {
    p[c.id] = c;
    c.children = [];
    return p;
}, {});

// then we build our tree
var tree = obj.items.reduce(function(p,c) {
    // if the parent_id is zero, we have found the root.
    if (!c.parent_id) {
        p = c;
    }
    // otherwise, figure out who the parent is and add this one as a child
    else {
        objDict[c.parent_id].children.push(c);
    }
    return p;
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(tree));
```

This would give you an object that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "lable": "Test 1.0",
    "parent_id": 0,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 32,
            "lable": "Test 1.1",
            "parent_id": 12,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "lable": "Test 1.2",
            "parent_id": 12,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 45,
                    "lable": "Test 1.2.1",
                    "parent_id": 2,
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Which should now be easy for you to process. Start with the root and create a node, then do a depth first search down each child making nested nodes as needed.

Something like this:

```
processTree(tree, document.getElementById("list"));

function processTree(node, element) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = node.lable;
    element.appendChild(li);
    if (node.children.length) {
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        li.appendChild(ul);
        // note: you might want / need to actual sort the children first
        // but it's not clear from the OP if sorting by id will always give the right order
        for (var i=0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
           processTree(node.children[i], ul);
        }
    }
}
```

To give you a working example like this:

```js
var obj = {
  items: [{
    id: 45,
    lable: "Test 1.2.1",
    parent_id: 2
  }, {
    id: 12,
    lable: "Test 1.0",
    parent_id: 0
  }, {
    id: 32,
    lable: "Test 1.1",
    parent_id: 12
  }, {
    id: 2,
    lable: "Test 1.2",
    parent_id: 12
  }]
}

var objDict = obj.items.reduce(function(p, c) {
  p[c.id] = c;
  c.children = [];
  return p;
}, {});

var tree = obj.items.reduce(function(p, c) {
  if (!c.parent_id) {
    p = c;
  } else {
    objDict[c.parent_id].children.push(c);
  }
  return p;
}, {});

processTree(tree, document.getElementById("list"));

function processTree(node, element) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = node.lable;
  element.appendChild(li);
  if (node.children.length) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    li.appendChild(ul);
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      processTree(node.children[i], ul);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Comment: thnxs, i was stuck on determining the child to parent relation or how to achieve this, i noticed that "parent_id" value is equal to its parents "id" value in the object. I didn't even think of transforming the array into a tree

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using recursion. I've used a helper function that returns an array of the children for a given parent_id.  I hope you find it helpful.

```
'use strict';

(function() {

    function childrenOf(targetId, items) {
        var children = [];
        items.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item.parent_id === targetId) {
                children.push(item);
            }
        });
        return children;
    }

    function nestedList(id, items) {
        var result = '';
        var children = childrenOf(id, items);
        if (children.length) {
            result = '<ul>';
            children.forEach(function(child) {
                result += '<li>';
                result += child.label;
                result += nestedList(child.id,items);
                result += '</li>';
            });
            result += '</ul>';
        }
        return result;
    }

    var json = {
        items:[
            {id:45 , label:"Test 1.2.1", parent_id: 2},
            {id:12, label:"Test 1.0", parent_id: 0},
            {id:32, label:"Test 1.1", parent_id: 12},
            {id:2, label:"Test 1.2", parent_id: 12}
        ]
    }

    var rootId = 0;
    var output = nestedList(rootId, json.items);
    console.log('<html><body>');
    console.log(output);
    console.log('</body></html>');



})();
```

It produces the following output:

```
<html>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Test 1.0
            <ul>
                <li>Test 1.1</li>
                <li>Test 1.2
                    <ul>
                        <li>Test 1.2.1</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Every call to `childrenOf` requires you to loop through the whole list *again* which isn't very efficient.

Comment: You're quite right. It would be more efficient to run through the array first and generate a series of child arrays up front.